# Adding Rows dynamically to GridView in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I use the following code for adding Rows dynamically to GridView in ASP.NET.

```
ViewState("CourseFeesDetails") = dsGetStudentCourseFeesDetail

    If ViewState("CourseFeesDetails") IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim dtCourseTable As New DataTable
        dtCourseTable = CType(ViewState("CourseFeesDetails"), DataTable)
        Dim drCurrentRow As DataRow = Nothing
        Dim txtFeesAmt As New System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox

        If dtCourseTable.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            For i = 1 To nNoOfInstallments
                drCurrentRow = dtCourseTable.NewRow()
                i = i + 1
                dtCourseTable.Rows.Add(drCurrentRow)

            Next

            ViewState("CourseFeesDetails") = dtCourseTable

            gvCourseFeeDisplay.DataSource = dtCourseTable
            gvCourseFeeDisplay.DataBind()
        End If
End If
```

It does add the number of rows, but adds 1 extra. What should I do?

Comment: what is `nNoOfInstallments`?  And second, storing your datatable in ViewState is asking for performance issues between the client and server.

Comment: `nNoOfInstallments` is an integer which has the value from my table. I have to set the no. of rows based on this.

Comment: Why are you doing `i = i + 1`, the `For` loop will step by 1 for you? If anything, I am surprised you are not getting less than the number of rows you think should be added, half the amount in fact.

Comment: @KarlAnderson, I do get the correct no of rows. Only thing, 1 extra roww gets added.

Comment: @Aishvarya - Have you stepped through (debugged) the loop to see why it is doing one extra loop?

Comment: @KarlAnderson, good catch.  Aishvarya, if you mean for i to increase by two each time, you should at least do `For i As Integer = 1 To nNoOfInstallments Step 2`, which means you want i to increase by two each time.

Comment: Yeah, I did that. It shows the count right. But I am not able to understnad where it does the addition of the extra row.

Comment: You can comment i=i+1 and see if it helps.

Comment: @Aishvarya - so do you want to count by one through the loop or count by two?

Comment: @Karl, I need count 1 only. If noOfInstallments is 1 I need to have only 1 dynamically added row.

Comment: @Aishvarya - when you debugged, what was the value of `nNoOfInstallments` and how many rows were added?

Comment: @Aishvarya - well I do not see how this loop is not counting by two, given the `i = i + 1` line.

Comment: Are you expecting the one from ViewState to go away? `dtCourseTable = CType(ViewState("CourseFeesDetails"), DataTable)` loads any previous rows you had.